# MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo in Xcode 8 beta 6

Tags: swift, xcode

Up to Xcode 8 beta 5, I could access the event info in a MusicEventIterator, using something like:

```
var type: MusicEventType = 0
var stamp: MusicTimeStamp = 0
var data: UnsafePointer<()>? = nil
var size: UInt32 = 0

while(hasCurrentEvent != false) {
        MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iterator!, &stamp, &type,
        &data, &size) 
    // do stuff with stamp, type, data...
}
```

I managed to get some help at the Apple dev site on dealing with "data", but getting data in the first place is also broken. I get a warning about using "UnsafeRawPointer" in the declaration of "data", and an error about not being able to use data as an inout argument in the call to MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo()... 
Though I know they're making things more deterministic and future-proof (i.e., for the compiler), it's incredibly frustrating to have the C-interop stuff changing every few months. My MIDI file parser code has already changed 3 times...

For reference, MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo has the signature:

```
func MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(_ inIterator: MusicEventIterator,
 _ outTimeStamp: UnsafeMutablePointer<MusicTimeStamp>,
 _ outEventType: UnsafeMutablePointer<MusicEventType>,
 _ outEventData: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>>,
 _ outEventDataSize: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>) -> OSStatus
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: further, looking over https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md, it's not even clear to me how the "pointee" in UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafePointer<Void>> is supposed to be represented....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [latest reference of `MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1501702-musiceventiteratorgeteventinfo) shows this:

> ## Declaration
>
> ```
> func MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(_ inIterator: MusicEventIterator, 
>                                   _ outTimeStamp: UnsafeMutablePointer<MusicTimeStamp>, 
>                                   _ outEventType: UnsafeMutablePointer<MusicEventType>, 
>                                   _ outEventData: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>, 
>                                   _ outEventDataSize: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>) -> OSStatus
> ```

The third parameter `outEventData` is of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>`.
Generally, when an API claims `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`, you declare a variable of type `T`, and pass it as an inout argument.

So, this should work:

```
var type: MusicEventType = 0
var stamp: MusicTimeStamp = 0
var data: UnsafeRawPointer? = nil //<- Declare a variable of type `UnsafeRawPointer?`.
var size: UInt32 = 0

while hasCurrentEvent != false {
    MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iterator!, &stamp, &type,
                                   &data, &size) //<- Pass it as an inout argument.
    // do stuff with stamp, type, data...
}
```

Comment: Yes, that does work, and it certainly seems simpler (I'm shocked I never tried it!). But then it just pushes the problems further down in the code. Where I try to read the "data" is now broken. I'm using: `let exTempo = data.pointee?.bindMemory(to: ExtendedTempoEvent.self, capacity: MemoryLayout<ExtendedTempoEvent>.size)`, which complains that data has no pointee.

Comment: @mrwheet, use `let exTempo = data?.bindMemory(to: ExtendedTempoEvent.self, capacity: 1)`. You'd better post another question including the code.

Comment: Nope, no worries; removing pointee from my code works as expected. Make sense, since using UnsafeRawPointer directly (to get "data") leaves out the extra layer of referencing (hence no need for pointee!). Thanks.

Comment: @mrwheet, you'd better care about the `capacity` argument of `bindMemory` method. It's counted by the type specified by `to`, not by bytes.

Comment: Oh, right... I hadn't noticed your use of "1" before. But I'm afraid I don't really understand the explanation. Apple's docs don't explain at all, either... What is capacity looking for, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @mrwheet, check the header doc shown in Quick Help. It's very similar to `count` in `Array` or many other types.

Comment: Hmm... that seems to say that it wants to know how many e.g., ExtendedTempoEvents to expect. I think this would always be 1, but  there's really no concrete way of knowing, is there? (I mean, in a standard MIDI file.)

Comment: @mrwheet, no. You need to know the number of elements by other means.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. It does make sense now. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same problem, this seems to work:

```
// Somewhere to put the raw midi data
var type: MusicEventType = 0
var stamp: MusicTimeStamp = -1
let data: UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?> = UnsafeMutablePointer<UnsafeRawPointer?>.allocate(capacity: MemoryLayout<MusicEventType>.size)

var size: UInt32 = 0
var tsChangeStamp: MusicTimeStamp = 0

while(hasCurrentEvent != false) {
        MusicEventIteratorGetEventInfo(iterator!, &stamp, &type, data, &size)
    // do stuff...
}
```